# How can I connect Ekiga to other VOIP services?

Tags: 12.04, voip, ekiga

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Ekiga does not work properly because I can't add other SIP services like (Poivy, VOIP Stunt etc.) I really need these VOIP services desperately.

Can anyone give me an alternative (not Skype) or a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Press F10 on account window (go to top menu), you will see entry Add SIP, h323 account.